# java best way to store 5/6 static pieces of related information

Tags: java, static, constants

I am trying to optimise some piece of code where there are 6 formulas that each return a double. Each formula is only one line long and has a title, and an explanation ( two strings).

```
textOutput.setString("Formula A: " + formulaResult + " explanation of formula... " );
```

when i noticed that the formula result, formula title and explanation were manually being added to a string for displaying the output, I figured there is a simpler, tidier way of doing this.

I would rather not create a class ( with 2 static strings) and a one line formula for each.
The reason for this is that some new formulas might be added, and some removed in the future.

I suppose if an XML file containing the 6 or so formulas with  a field for the two strings and the formula with the doubles were straightforward to implement I could look at that- but maybe that is a step too far.

Comment: Please provide some code.

Comment: I have shown the relevant code in the above.

Comment: I do this a lot too: `static final string BLAH_BLAH = ...`. I bet there is some i18n library that can not only store all these named strings, but also provide translation support for them as well. Looking forward to answers.

Comment: Contrary to what you said, I would recommend encapsulating related information in a class. Maybe create one class 'Formula' and your 6 different formulas are unique instances of this class.

Comment: I agree to @SoulDZIN. The best approach is using a `Formula` class and have different implementations. Also later on if the number of formulas increase or is dynamic you can go forward with the XML approach or why not a NoSQL solution if the number grows humongous ^_^